# Why does sqlite 3.8.7 get installed as sqlite 3.8.6?

Tags: sqlite

On a fresh CentOS 5, compiling SQLite using the [current tarball](https://www.sqlite.org/2014/sqlite-autoconf-3080700.tar.gz) for 3.8.7, the version being installed ends up in `/usr/local/lib` as **3.8.6**:

```
bash-3.2# make install
make[1]: Entering directory `/mongrel2/sqlite-autoconf-3080700'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/sh ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libsqlite3.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 libsqlite3.so.0 || { rm -f libsqlite3.so.0 && ln -s libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 libsqlite3.so.0; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 libsqlite3.so || { rm -f libsqlite3.so && ln -s libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 libsqlite3.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libsqlite3.lai /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libsqlite3.a /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to Daniel Kennedy](http://osdir.com/ml/sqlite-users/2014-10/msg00476.html):

> It's normal. I think that number is only supposed to change if the new
>   release is not ABI compatible with the previous. It's a coincidence
>   that "8.6" matches the tail of the previous release number. Earlier
>   releases also used "libsqlite3.so.0.8.6".